# Prove that $x \mapsto f(x)=\alpha\|x_0\|$ is a linear functional on $M$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed linear space, $M=\{x:x=\alpha\,x_0,\;\alpha\;\text{is a scalar}\},\;x_0\neq 0$ be a member of $X$ and define \begin{align} f:&M\to \Bbb{R},\\& x \mapsto f(x)=\alpha\|x_0\|.\end{align}
I want to prove that $f$ is a linear functional on $M$.

**HERE'S WHAT I'VE DONE**

Let $\gamma,\,\eta\in \Bbb{R}$ and $x,y\in M,$ then,
\begin{align} f(\gamma x+\eta y)&=\alpha\|\gamma x_0+\eta y_0\|\\&\leq \alpha\left(\|\gamma x_0\|+\|\eta y_0\|\right)\\&= \alpha|\gamma |\|x_0\|+\alpha |\eta |\| y_0\|\\&= |\gamma |f(x)+|\eta |f(y).\end{align}
I'm stuck here but I think I'm missing something. Can you please share with me, what I'm missing?

Comment: The $y_0$ should be an $x_0$.

Comment: @Kenny Wong: Really?

Comment: @Mike what is $y_0$

Comment: You're meant to say, if $x = \alpha x_0$, and $y = \beta x_0$ (for some $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$), then $f(\gamma x + \eta y) = f ((\gamma \alpha + \eta \beta) x_0) = (\gamma \alpha + \eta \beta) \| x_0 \|$...

Comment: @Kenny Wong: Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mike I mistyped. My apologies

Comment: @Mike No problem!

Comment: @mathworker21: No problems, we all make mistakes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to Kenny Wong:

Let $\gamma ,\eta \in \Bbb{R}$ and $x,y\in M,$ then, $x=\alpha x_0$ and $y=\beta x_0,$ for some $\alpha,\beta\in \Bbb{R}.$ So,
\begin{align} f(\gamma x+\eta y)&=f(\gamma (\alpha x_0)+\eta (\beta x_0))\\&=f((\gamma \alpha +\eta \beta) x_0)\\&=(\gamma \alpha +\eta \beta) \|x_0\|\\&=\gamma \alpha \|x_0\| +\eta \beta \|x_0\|\\&=\gamma f( x)+\eta f(  y).\end{align}
Since $x,y\in M$ and $\gamma ,\eta \in \Bbb{R}$ are arbitrary, then
\begin{align} f(\gamma x+\eta y)=\gamma f( x)+\eta f(  y),\;\;\forall\;x,y\in M,\;\forall\; \gamma ,\eta \in \Bbb{R}.\end{align}
Thus, $f$ is a linear functional on $M$.